# Variance of random variable with distribution $2(x+1)^{-3}$

Tags: probability, integration, random-variables, expectation, variance

I have to calculate $Var(X)$, with $f(x)= 2(x+1)^{-3}$ for $x>0$

I have tried using $Var(X) = E(X^2) - E(X)^2$

for $E(X)$ i managed to get $1$ from the integral, however the integral i get for $E(X^2): 2(ln(x+1) + (4x+3)/(2x^2+4x+2))$ is diverging

Any help would be appreciated, thanks

Comment: The variance does not exist.

Comment: I would say that the variance was infinite for that density function